# Getting Routing Error(Route doesn't match)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to update multi-select list on change but I am getting a routing error.
 I call this with an onchange event `$.post("/levels/category_lists_for_level"`

I have an action called `category_lists_for_level` in a controller called `level`.

My routes file looks like this.

```
match '/levels/category_lists_for_level/:id'  => 'levels#category_lists_for_level'
resources :levels 
resources :levels , :collection => {:category_lists_for_level => :get}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I never had any problem in Rails 2, all I used to add the collection.

Comment: Your question is terribly bad formated. Could you please reformat it? It is not about style, it is not understandable this way.

Comment: Are you still using rails 2 or have you upgraded to 3? (difficult to tell from your question)

Comment: I am using Rails 3 now.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to say exactly what you need since as others have said you are missing some info, but you have a few apparent things going on here:

1. You are duplicating routes
2. You have the route set on a collection and a member
3. You are allowing multiple requests types (get and post) to access this route.

If you would like to have this operate on a collection you just need:

```
resources :levels do
  post "category_lists_for_level", :on => :collection 
end
```

or on a member:

```
resources :level do 
  get "category_lists_for_level", :on => :member
end
```

This will reduce your routes. Just use `rake routes | grep level` to get the routes for this controller.

Take a look at [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) for some more info.